# Angular 4 AOT Compiler

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, aot

I want to set up the AOT compiler for my application

When I run `node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json` it compiles successfully and gives no errors.

But when I try to run `ng serve` it gives me this error:

**Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.**

```
Error: Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.
    at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain (/path/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/entry_resolver.js:128:11)
    at AotPlugin._setupOptions (/path/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:143:50)
    at new AotPlugin (/path/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:26:14)
    at _createAotPlugin (/path/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:55:12)
    at Object.exports.getNonAotConfig (/path/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:70:19)
    at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig (/path/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-config.js:27:37)
    at Class.run (/path/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/serve.js:38:98)
    at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (/path/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve.js:110:26)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/main/app.module.ngfactory';

console.log('Running AOT compiled');
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Comment: Why you're mixing `ngc` and `ng`? `пg` converts bootstrap code for aot. For `ng serve` you should use `bootstrapModule`

Comment: How to serve the app then? @yurzui

Comment: create `main.ts` for jit.

Comment: I have a `main-jit.ts` for that but I don't know how to serve the AOT files not the normal JIT files?

Comment: AFAIK there is `ng serve --aot` for that purpose

Comment: nope the same error again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json` compiles all files into output folder. You can use any http server to run files from that folder.

However this is not how it's usually done when developing with `angular-cli`. `ng serve` uses its own development server that doesn't care about `output` folder. As stated in the [official docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/serve):

> `ng serve` builds the application and starts a web server.
>
> ... below are the additional
>   options.
>
> -- aot

So you need to use `--aot` option:

```
ng serve --aot
```

And you don't need to modify the `main.ts` file. It should have `boostrapModule` and not `boostrapModuleFactory` method.

Comment: do not modify `main.ts`

Comment: @rexhin And add `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: I have a `.angular-cli.json`
main.ts:

`
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/src/app/main/app.module.ngfactory';

console.log('Running AOT compiled');
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
`

Comment: @rexhin, this is modified version. `angular-cli` has `boostrapModule` method, not `bootstrapModuleFactory`. revert it

Comment: No, It has a `bootstrapModuleFactory`

 https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#compile

Comment: @rexhin, your problem is that you're trying to mix `angular-cli` and **manual** AOT compilation. Choose one. If you work with `angular-cli` and want it to do the AOT compilation for you, revert the `main.ts` and use `ng serve --aot`

Comment: What is the purpose if we are bootstrap again the AppModule then? Shouldn't we bootstrap AppModuleNgFactory?

The `main.bundle.js.map` is larger in `--aot` about 300kb in my case but the `vendor.bundle.js.map` is 1mb less then the normal `ng serve`

Is this normal?

Comment: @rexhin, again, `angular-cli` will bootstrap `AppModuleNgFactory` for you

Comment: So to conclude. main.ts remains unchanged. If I run ng serve it will be a jit compilation. If I run ng serve --aot it will be the AOT compilation bootstraping the AppModuleNgFactory right?